# What is the key size and security level of attribute-based encryption schemes?

Tags: abe

I am studying the ABE for my masters theses however I want to calculate the key and it's strength. I have done a research about the KP-ABE and I want to know the size of the key and how to determine it's strength because I want to decrease the key size yet keep a good security as well.

What is the key size of attribute-based encryption?  How do you calculate its strength? A math example would be very helpful.

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/223 but be sure to properly classify your scheme into the appropriate types.